# Specific Polymer elements not importing. 404 Not found error

Tags: html, polymer, importerror

On my web page, I attempt to import the paper-toast element from the same directory as the other two Polymer elements. All have been installed with Bower and all have the same privileges.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>New Movement Entertainment</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href=css/home.css type=text/css>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <script src=scripts/jquery.js></script>
```

However, upon page load I am greeted with a 404 Not Found for the paper-toast import. I have tried reinstalling the element and even putting its folder in the paper-input directory (which I know imports fine). Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Don't include the Jquery twice.

Comment: Where is it already being included? within the imports?

Comment: The jquery.js file is just a script file filled with jquery functions for the page

Comment: Can you paste the exact 404 error you're seeing?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)